# C# run method multiple time concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following C# code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents\DailyData", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        for (int ii = 0; ii < files.Length; ii++)
        {
            perFile(files[ii]);
        }
```

Where per file opens each file and creates a series of generic lists, then writes the results to a file.

Each iteration takes about 15 minutes.

I want the `perFile` method to execute concurrently eg not wait for the current iteration to finish before starting the next one.

My questions are:

How would I do this?

How can I control how many instances of `perFile` are running concurrently

How can I determine how many concurrent instances of `perFile` my computer can handle at one time

Comment: what you are looking for is possible but you wont get any benefit from it since your hard disk is not reading multiple sectors concurrently. you may get benefit if you have ssd.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary: We can't tell from the question whether or not the `perFile` method is disk-bound. (Obviously there's a certain amount of disk i/o happening, but impossible to know whether that's the bottleneck.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401(v=vs.110).aspx) to do what you need if you're using .Net 4.5 and above, You can control how many threads to use by providing a `ParallelOptions` with `MaxDegreeOfParalleism`  set to a number you like.

Example code:

```
ParallelOptions POptions = new ParallelOptions();
POptions.MaxDegreeOfParalleism = ReplaceThisWithSomeNumber;

Parallel.For(0,files.Length,POptions,(x) => {perFile(files[x]);});
```

Note that your program will be IO bound though (read [Asynchronous IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on how to tackle that)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989238%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set max count of running `perFile`.